# ¿Como funciona un return a || b de una funcion en recursion en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Esta es una función recursiva para mostrar en pantalla la forma de obtener X numero a traves de un calculo matematico donde solo se puede `sumar 5 (+5)` o `multiplicar por 3 (*3)`, teniendo como base el numero 1:

**Ejemplo:**

Si quiero llegar a 13 desde 1, primero multiplico por 3, luego sumo 5 y luego de nuevo sumo 5.

```
findSolution(13) === (((1 * 3) + 5) + 5)
```

**Codigo Javascript:**

```
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(current, history) {
    if (current == target)
      return history;
    else if (current > target)
      return null;
    else
      return find(current + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(current * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}

console.log(findSolution(13));
(((1 * 3) + 5) + 5)
```

**Iterando únicamente usando +5:**

```
6,1
11,1
16,1
null
```

**Iterando multiplicando por 3:**

```
3,1
9,1
27,1
null
```

**Por lo tanto quisiera saber:** ¿Como funciona el `return find() || find()`?, ya que no se como hace la función para decidir entre +5 o *3, o ¿si genera automáticamente dos llamados a FIND cada vez que haga un return, y a su vez dos llamados por opcion?, algo parecido al siguiente árbol:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El operador `||` en JavaScript evalua la expresión de la izquierda y si esta no es un valor *falsy* (null en este caso) la devuelve, de lo contrario devuelve la expresión de la derecha.

En este caso esta línea:

```
return find(current + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
         find(current * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
```

Sería equivalente a:

```
var left = find(current + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)");
return left ? left : find(current * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
```

O a esto:

```
var left = find(current + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)");
if (left) {
    return left;
} else {
    return find(current * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
}
```

Pero sin crear ninguna variable intermedia ni ejecutar la expresión de la izquierda dos veces

Comment: @Victor-Random acá tienes la ejecución de tu código paso por paso: https://goo.gl/Asfmtp. Es un poco dificil de seguir, pero muestra exactamente el camino que tomará la ejecución en cada llamada recursiva

Answer (score 2):

Para complentar la respuesta de @Carlos Muñoz:

Estos serian los llamados de recursion:

```
find(1, "1")
  find(6, "(1 + 5)")
    find(11, "((1 + 5) + 5)")
      find(16, "(((1 + 5) + 5) + 5)")
        muy grande
      find(33, "(((1 + 5) + 5) * 3)")
        muy grande
    find(18, "((1 + 5) * 3)")
      muy grande
  find(3, "(1 * 3)")
    find(8, "((1 * 3) + 5)")
      find(13, "(((1 * 3) + 5) + 5)")
        Encontrado!
```